# vimコマンドを使用後のエラーについて。

Tags: git, git-bash

Gitで下記コマンドを打つとvimはGitコマンドではないというエラーが出てしまいます。 
どうすればエラーが出ずうまくいくようにできますか。他のPCで下記のコマンドを打つとエラーは出ていません。 
Gitはgit for windowsを使用しています。 
【コマンド】

```
$ git vim aaa.html
```

【エラー内容】

```
git: 'vim' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

Comment: `git vim aaa.html`と実行した場合、何が起る事を期待されていますか？  `vim`が起動して、`aaa.html` の編集に入る事でしょうか。（他のPCではエラーが出ていないというのは、勘違いではないかと推測しますので、ご確認下さい）

Answer (score 3):

デフォルトではgitにvimというサブコマンドはありませんが、
サブコマンドvimが使えたPCは、

- (gitの)エイリアスが設定されている。
- PATHに`git-vim`という実行ファイルがある。(自作サブコマンド)

という可能性はあります。

エイリアスは

```
$ git config --get alias.vim
```

で、確認できます。

PATHに`git-vim`があるかは、Windowsなら

```
> where git-vim
```

で確認できるかと思います。

Answer (score 2):

`git vim` というコマンドは存在しません。コミットメッセージを編集する際などに vim を使いたい、ということでしょうか？だとしたら、

```
EDITOR=vim
```

の環境変数を設定すると実現できます。